# Mechanism to convert simple rotational motion to reciprocating rotation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I'm looking to make something like a paint shaker - but I'm wanting to create perfectly rotational reciprocating motion. The picture below shows what I've been considering. The interface could be a problem, especially after a bit of use. I'm just wondering if anyone had a better way of doing it? [image]

Many thanks,

Comment: Check out Scotch Yoke.

Comment: @SolarMike That's essentially the same mechanism as above. In any case, it converts rotary to linear reciprocation. I need rotary to rotary reciprocation

Comment: No, it's not. but fine.

Comment: Scotch yoke is a cam mechanism and you have a bar mechanism. But why not use a crank rocker fourbar mechanism whisc is what jstola is showing.

Comment: "I'm wanting to create perfectly rotational reciprocating motion"  That's easy -- it can't be done, at least not in this universe.  Please _edit your question_ to explain what is _adequate_ for you.

Comment: @TimWescott How is jsotola's answer not perfectly rotational?

Comment: In practice whatever you mount it on will suffer considerable vibration, so the center axis of the paint can won't be steady.

Comment: @TimWescott I'll obviously add bits to constrain the mechanism properly so that should be minimised if not eradicated. Also what I want to shake is alot smaller and lighter than a paint can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.

[image]

Comment: you may want to tell how to dimension this

Comment: @joojaa that would be dependent on the actual application ... the question is specifically about converting motion ... no idea if it is actually about a paint shaker