# Mechanism for fast vibration

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, vibration

What mechanisms can be used to apply fast vibration to an object? One way is [this](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54409/mechanism-to-convert-simple-rotational-motion-to-reciprocating-rotation?noredirect=1#comment103342_54409).

What are some other ways to do it?

I'm looking to go as fast as possible - 100s of Hz if possible.

Thankyou

Comment: Rotating offset mass.

Comment: some audio speakers vibrate at frequencies above 10 kHz

Comment: `100s of Hz` is quite a range ... please be more precise

Comment: @jsotola I can't, as its for investigation. But why would it make any difference? Do you know different mechanisms for creating 100Hz as you do for creating 200? I'm looking for a mechanical way (hence mechanism) to go as fast as possible. Not electromagnetics

Comment: Well motors are most likely electric so electromagnetics. But yeah springs and a offcenter mass on motor can easily do 100hz. See vibratory tumbler.

Comment: @joojaa Cheers, vibratory tumbler is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for

Comment: Tell us precisely what you are doing. Pictures, weights, materials, part numbers - everything. Write us a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 Hz is what we call „bass“ in music. So a well proven device is called „speaker“, which comes in many flavors, and which is excited by electric signals, like sine, square, saw, noise, voice etc.

Try picking a suitable system and modify it.

Here‘s a short video about [sugar on a vibrating speaker](https://www.pond5.com/de/stock-footage/item/22039903-sugar-loud-speaker-cone-vibrating-sound).

Comment: Thanks, yea tbh I've tried this but its just not enough movement. I need a bigger amplitude than a speaker can provide. Have also tried attaching magnets with a coil, and getting somewhere but against difficult to get enough amplitude

Comment: How much amplitude do you need? Which mass etc. do you have to move? Can you please add more specifica to your question?

Comment: Don;t know. That's why I need a mechanism to make a bigger amplitude to find out.

Comment: Ok. 100 Hz are 6000 rpm, which brings me to drilling machines or fuel driven motors. Think more violently ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An electromagnetic buzzer is effectively a solenoid with the switch wired to the coil supply. Closing the primary power to the coil causes the solenoid to retract, which then opens the switch causing the solenoid to extend, closing the switch.

This is repeated for the duration of the primary switch closure. The vibration created by the solenoid movement can be transferred to an object by mounting the solenoid on that object.

One can use a high powered switching device such as a MOSFET operated by a PWM circuit to adjust the frequency as desired.